# How can I create a shared_ptr to a member?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm not sure if I'm suffering more from a documentation error or a headache, so...

What I want to do is create a shared_ptr that shares ownership with another, but which references a member of the object instead of the whole object. Simple example, starting point...

```
struct s
{
  int a, b;
};

shared_ptr<s> s1 (new s);  //  pointing to whole object
```

From [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), constructor (8) of shared_ptr is...

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

The description mentions "Constructs a shared_ptr which shares ownership information with r, but holds an unrelated and unmanaged pointer ptr ... such as in the typical use cases where ptr is a member of the object managed by r".

So... Was `T` just accidentally missed from the template in that constructor, or am I missing something? In fact, Y looks like it's wrong to me too, so just generally is that constructor described correctly?

What I'm hoping I can do is something like this...

```
shared_ptr<int> s2 (s1, &(s1.get ()->a));
```

`s2` points to member `a` (an `int`), but shares ownership of the whole object with `s1`.

Is that sane?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would you want a shared_ptr to a member var that isn't allocated on the heap?  i.e. why not just use a raw pointer for s2?

Comment: @RC - to make sure that if the original shared_ptr gets deallocated, the object itself doesn't - ie to make sure that s2 doesn't become a dangling pointer. In a real world example, the scopes of s1 and s2 won't be the same.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly sane. Also you don't need a `.get()`.

Comment: Ahhh... I've never used shared_ptr like that.  @Steve314, based on your comment, and then checking the documentation that makes sense.  Didn't know you could that.  Learned my "something new" for today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `T` parameter is a template parameter on the `shared_ptr` itself, whereas the `Y` parameter is a template parameter on that particular `shared_ptr` constructor.  Something like this:

```
template< class T >
class shared_ptr
{
     template< class Y >
     shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
}
```

As for the example code you've posted, that looks fine to me.

Comment: Everyone's right - you win for being a little bit faster. I'm feeling a tad stupid - I obviously haven't been doing much template stuff recently. I completely forgot about member templates.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is correct.  You're forgetting that this is the documentation of a constructor on the class template `shared_ptr<T>` i.e. the class-qualified declaration of the constructor is:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename Y>
shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr);
```

So in your example `T` is `int` and `Y` is `s`.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is the template parameter of the class, not of the constructor. And this is exactly as it needs to be: A pointer to a member has to have the type of the member and forget/erase (see type-erasure) the type of the containing object (`Y`, in this case).

The code you posted should work, you can even write it a little simpler as:

```
shared_ptr<int> s2 (s1, &s1->a);
```

Comment: For some reason I'm never sure about the precedence of `&` - probably because I always add extra parens rather than checking. The `get` was also deliberate, but I'm not sure the making-things-more-explicit reasoning makes sense. I should really stick with blaming my headache.